# Fixing /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager, interface

I recently tried to get my USB to Ethernet adaptor working (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962987/getting-a-usb-to-ethernet-adaptor-which-is-already-recognized-by-the-kernel-to) question, it's currently not working), since my computers built-in ethernet adaptor started becoming flaking and often simply stops working.

While browsing the web in hope of finding a solution I tried numerous suggestions and modified my `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` a number of times, without saving, unfortunately, the original.

Now my network manager GUI looks crazy (for privacy I "blued out" my Wifi connection)

[image]

How can I revert it to the original?

The `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`  currently read

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

resp.

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Create a live USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) with the same version of Ubuntu that you are using.
2. Boot from it
3. Mount your hard drive
4. Copy the files you want to revert from the live image to your installation hard drive.
5. Reboot and remove the USB

Alternatively, you can boot the iso in a Virtualbox.

In my Ubuntu 16.04, those files look like this:

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Comment: I can confirm that in my Ubuntu 16.04, those files look like same.